# Search Server Common 2007 Returns Memory Load Too High

Tags: search

Search Server Common 2007 returns Memory Load Too High message in ULS log.  I observed that there is about 1 minute down time for Search Server.  Also, the down time of Search Server occurs at exactly the same time daily(01:32).  After 1 minute down time, the search server resumes normal.

Details: Sharepoint Server 2007 running on Windows Server 2008 R2

Please help.

Regards,
Wilson

Answer (score 0):

So SharePoint has IIS setup to recycle application pools at around that time. I would suggest that is why you are seeing the behaviour.
To check go to the server running search using REmote desktop.

Open up IIS console, expand the server node and choose application pools. Select the search app pool and choose recycling settings in right hand pane. Check the specified time.

Please don't stop it from recycling because it is freeing up RAM when the app pool recycles but change it to a more appropriate time. If you have two search boxes then you can stagger the recycle so the service is always available.

More info here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754494(v=ws.10).aspx